# Is this JSON data correct in my DB field?

Tags: json, typescript, postgresql

For the first time ever, I'm including a JSON column type in a Postgres database.  I'm doing this because the type of data in it varies greatly and because the data will never need to be searchable.

Here's an example of what I what to convert into JSON: `visualization_options: ['Grid', 'Filmstrip']`

So I used `JSON.stringify` and ended up with this in the DB: `"{visualization_options: Grid,Filmstrip}"`

It's not exactly what I expected so thought I should check with the community here to see if this is correct or not.

Comment: I don't see this `visualization_options: ['Grid', 'Filmstrip']` as valid JSON, so you will need to provide more information as to how you went from that to JSON.stringify to the database entry. **Add as update to question**.

Comment: Ask your database: SELECT CAST('{visualization_options: Grid,Filmstrip}' AS json);

Comment: The string you show, including the double quote marks, is valid as a JSON string.  But without the enclosing double quotes, it is not valid as a JSON object, which is what you presumably intend it as.  It is also hard to guess what code you used to get from one to the other.  Please show the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you're using is incorrect.
I checked this on an online compiler and it seems to have worked so I'm hoping it does for you:

```
const visualizationOptions = ["Grid", "Filmstrip"];
const jsonRepresentation = JSON.stringify(visualizationOptions);
```

This will produce this:
`["Grid", "Filmstrip"]`